# rvest only returns the headers

Tags: r, rvest

The code below only returns only the column headers. I have tried several ways to do it but with no luck.

```
library(rvest)
the <- read_html("https://www.timeshighereducation.com/world-university-rankings/2018/regional-ranking#!/page/0/length/25/sort_by/rank/sort_order/asc/cols/stats")
rating <- the %>% 
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  html_table()
rating
```

Comment: look at `read_html(your_url) %>% html_text %>% cat`, and you'll see the table is indeed empty. likely the contents are generated dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the Table is loaded before the page. There are many ways to do :

One of the most simple in this case is to use RSelenium as webdriver, and collect the results with :

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.timeshighereducation.com/world-university-rankings/2018/regional-ranking#!/page/0/length/25/sort_by/rank/sort_order/asc/cols/stats"
rD <- rsDriver()
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$navigate(url)

page <- read_html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])
table <- page %>% html_nodes("table") %>% html_table()

table
```

Another way,is to interpret the json result of the website transaction, the corresponding url https://www.timeshighereducation.com/sites/default/files/the_data_rankings/asia_university_rankings_2018_limit0_c36ae779f4180136af6e4bf9e6fc1081.json.

Hope this will helps

Gottavianoni